# Max limit of message in SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am trying to send notifications through SignalR. It works perfectly.

But what is the maximum size of a message we can send through SignalR?

Does it have any official limit as such?

Answer (score 15):

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1205

It's recommended to keep below 32K/message

Comment: Am I correct to assume that enabling/disabling compression has no effect on this. Network traffic compression must happen after signalR is done doing its thing, or is the web socket protocol immune to the compression settings altogether?

Answer (score 15):

In .Net Core 3+, You can configure SignalR in ConfigureServices method in your startup class.

```
services.AddSignalR(o =>
{
    o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10240; // bytes
});
```

Comment: What if max limit of client in SignalR?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-8.0#buffer-management - just adding this link as it's got some useful info related to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

maximum message size can be increased manually,
visit the following link:

[How to change SignalR maximum message size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248464/how-to-change-signalr-maximum-message-size)

Answer (score -7):

it's 64kb. if you want to send more than that from client to server than use another tool.

Comment: another tool like what? this answer is not complete, you need to elaborate more and show a solution

Comment: the question is asking for the size so i gave the size. if you must know, you can use ajax server side calls to accomplish that or you can set the signalr transport to use server sent events, forever frame or long polling when starting the hub on the client side for instance like this:  $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['serverSentEvents','foreverFrame','longPolling'] }).start()