# Transfer a long string from SignalR IHubProxy

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I want to transfer a byte stream from a IHubProxy to another client. I'm trasnfering the byte stream as a string. I was able to transfer small text without any issue. But when i'm transferring large string (which is a image converted to a bytestream and to a string) I can't trasnfer the string. How can I transfer a large string?

```
        string username = Console.ReadLine();

        var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:51428/");
        IHubProxy myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("ScannerHub"); //This should be same as Hub Name

        //Establishing the connection
        connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to start: {0}", task.Exception.GetBaseException());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success! Connected with client connection id {0}", connection.ConnectionId);

                //After connection is established. Register the printer client with client information
                myHub.Invoke("RegisterClient", username, connection.ConnectionId, "Printer").ContinueWith(task2 =>
                {
                    if (task2.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred during the method call {0}", task2.Exception.GetBaseException());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Successfully Registred");
                    }
                });

                //In the client (here it is Printer Client) there is a method named getScanRequest
                //This method retrieves the scan request and processes it accordingly.
                //What is done here is that, in the HubProxy we listen to the calls on current clients 
                //getScanRequest been hit. If hit. Execute that method.

                //Use a Func when you want to return a value
                //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317479/func-vs-action-vs-predicate

                //Func<string, byte[]> scanFunction;
                //scanFunction = Scan;

                //Action<string> printFunction;
                //printFunction = Scan;

                //myHub.On("getScanRequest", data => Console.WriteLine("Got Print Request " + data));
                //Register on a server side method with a callback function
                //myHub.On("getScanRequest", printFunction);
                //myHub.On("getScanRequest", data => Console.WriteLine("got print request from "+data));

                myHub.On<string>("getScanRequest", (clientUrl) =>
                    {
                        string scanByteStream = Scan(clientUrl);
                        try
                        {
                            myHub.Invoke("GetValueFromScanner", scanByteStream);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            var j = 0;
                        }
                    });
            }
```

Comment: How big is that string? Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012863/max-limit-of-message-in-signalr

Comment: i was able to transfer files up to 100MB with SignalR, it mainly depends on the client memory as at 200MB and up i was getting out of memory exception with the client reserved memory reaching 1.2GB, so i had to change the way i send files(to WCF), so i think its better to keep the size to the recommended limit as mentioned by the answer in Stephen comment.

Comment: I guess you need to split you text to chunk.