# How to change SignalR maximum message size?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I need to transfer large JSON messages in SignalR, but the maximum message size is limited by default, is there any way to increase that maximum size?

I have also find some relevant links but didn't find any proper solution:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this proprety [MaxIncomingWebSocketMessageSize](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/b73cbabe69bc48c4cb8d768148e157712a264ce9/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Configuration/IConfigurationManager.cs#L51) on `GlobalHost.Configuration`

Answer (score 5):

In .Net Core 3+, You can configure SignalR in ConfigureServices method in your startup class.

```
services.AddSignalR(o =>
            {
                o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10240;
            });
```