# How to decrease message size in signalR?

Tags: c#, signalr

I am working with siglarR self host service,my problem is message size,i want to decrease size from 1kb to only 30bytes because i am working on stock market service which send data very frequently but message size is low,but signalR takes minimum message size is 1kb ,it takes huge network bandwidth.if you have any solution please tell me.

Message example like '123|234.52|568'
// Please find the updated code below :

> ### application send message to server code

```
if (IsConnected)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsJsonData"].ToString()))
            {
                var obj = new
                {
                    id = SymbolId,
                    head = colName_no,
                    value = string.Format("{0:0.####}", Double.Parse(newValue))
                };
                _hub.Invoke("ServerAlert", SymbolId, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
            }
            else
            {
                _hub.Invoke("ServerAlert", SymbolId, data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            GenerateLog(ex.ToString() + "   " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtrow), "server hub");
        }
    }
```

> ##server side code##

```
public async void ServerAlert(string groupName, string message)
    {
        //await Clients.All.StockAlert(message);
        //string Delimiter = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SplitMessage"].ToString();
        Clients.Group(groupName).GroupStockAlert(message);
    }
```

> ### client side receive message code

```
objMainForm._hub.On("GroupStockAlert", (x) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    objMainForm.LastPingDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    string[] ChangeData = x.Split(new string[] { objMainForm.Delimeter }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    DataRow[] row = objMainForm.dtOnlineData.Select("SymbolId='" + ChangeData[0] + "'");
                    int RowIndex = objMainForm.dtOnlineData.Rows.IndexOf(row[0]);
                    DataTable Dt_ColumnName = objMainForm.dtAllHeaders.Select("RowNo='" + ChangeData[1] + "'").CopyToDataTable();
                    string exceldata = "t!!" + ChangeData[0] + "!!" + Dt_ColumnName.Rows[0]["Header"].ToString() + "!!" + ChangeData[2];
                    if (this.InvokeRequired)
                        this.Invoke(new livedata(this.ProcessServerData), new object[] { RowIndex, Dt_ColumnName.Rows[0]["Header"], ChangeData[2], ChangeData[0] });
                    ChangeData = null;
                    row = null;
                    RowIndex = 0;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
                }
            });
```

Thanks All

Comment: You are not providing enough information for anyone to work from. You should provide some example of what you are sending with each message. Does your message contain more data than you need for the client? Is there whitespace or other bloat in the message. Which model and version of SignalR (.Net 4x or .Net CORE)? This matters because the older model/version is text based, no streaming, etc. But the newer one could mean you are passing data differently.

Comment: Hi Frank,I am using .net 4x and in my message only 30 character.

Comment: That's good to know but we need more information as described above.

Comment: Hi @Frank M,
I have added code which i used.

Comment: Have you tried setting GlobalHost.Configuration. MaxIncomingWebSocketMessageSize ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248464/how-to-change-signalr-maximum-message-size

Comment: Hi @ChrisWong,
yes i tried but did not works.

Comment: Hi @https://stackoverflow.com/users/6263514/frank-m,
Can you check?