# How to increase allowed maximum file size over SignalR within an Azure Function C#

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

So I have come across a number of posts suggesting adding the following:

[Stackoverflow suggestion 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248464/how-to-change-signalr-maximum-message-size)

```
services.AddSignalR(o =>
            {
                o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10240;
            });
```

and adding the following:

[Stackoverflow suggestion 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262041/how-to-send-big-data-via-signalr-in-net-client/39854957#39854957)

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.MaxIncomingWebSocketMessageSize = null;
```

But none of these seemed to make a difference. I have a situation where its seconds and then fails. Multiple small files work fine though.

I tried increasing the server and handshake time outs on the hubconnection to 5 min as well, but nothing seems to work when trying to transfer over large files.

Is there anyone out there that has experienced the same and found a way around this ?